# CSS Drop Down Menu: 2 Columns and Headers

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm just coming from [6207957](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207957/make-css-drop-down-menu-2-columns) but unfortunately after hours of trying didn't get to what I exactly want... I'd like to have a 2 column dropdown menu with subheaders, ordered from top to bottom (not left to right).

Here is what I want:
[Dropdown menu with 2 columns and subheaders, ordered from top to bottom](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-26371309/dropdown.jpg.html)

But I only get this far:
[Wrong order direction (left to right) and not showing all products links](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-26371310/dropdown0.jpg.html)

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
 color: rgb(206,17,38);
}
nav {
 float: right; 
 margin-top:80px;
}
nav ul{
    
    height:35px;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
nav li{
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
 color:#ffffff;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
 font-family: 'Gruppo', cursive;
 font-size: 24px; 
 line-height:normal;
}
nav > ul > li > a:hover {
 font-family: 'Gruppo', cursive;
 font-size: 24px; 
 line-height:normal;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li {
 font-family: 'Gruppo', cursive;
 font-size: 18px; 
 line-height:normal;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a {
 font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height:normal;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover {
 font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height:normal; 
    color:rgb(206,17,38);
}
nav li a{   
    color:rgb(0,56,147);
    display:block;  
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 25px;
    text-align:center;
}
nav li a:hover, nav ul li:hover a{
    background: rgb(0,56,147);
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
nav li ul{
    background: rgb(0,56,147);
    display:none;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:700px;
    z-index:200;
    /*top:1em;
    /*left:0;*/
}
nav li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
nav li li {    
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px; 
    width:350px;
}
nav li:hover li a{
    background:none;
}
nav li ul a{
    display:block;
    font-style:normal;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align:left;
}
nav li ul a:hover, nav li ul li:hover a{
    background:rgb(0,56,147);
    border:0px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
nav p{
    clear:left;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Product Group Heading 1
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Product Group Heading 2
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 6</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Product Group Heading 3
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 8</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Product Group Heading 4
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 10</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Product Group Heading 5
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 11</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you change the markup at all?

Comment: Yes, I can change everything I like. But I'd like to keep the ´<ul> <li>´ structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code below to the end of your CSS, it will do the trick.

```
nav li ul li ul {
  position: static;
  width: auto; /*extra new*/
}

nav li ul li ul li {
    float: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u0vyezwh/2/

Comment: Thank you very much, it works somehow, bot leaves some blue filled background areas to the rigth (you can't see them on JSFiddle because its aligned to the right). Just delete `float: right;` in `nav`and you will see.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! But same as with @Vel solution: Is it possible to order from top to bottom (not left to right)?

Comment: It's not possible to do that with the css currently, but you can modify you HTML code (the orders of the items) to achieve that.

Comment: Sad, but ok :) Thanks very much! BTW: I solved the triangle-problem with an image...

Answer (score 0):

add to **nav li**

```
{position:relative}
```

change **nav li ul** to **nav > ul > li > ul** because all the uls are positioned absolute. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7bncrtx/)

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it works! But its still ordered from left to right (not top down)...